# Arrows not showing in jQuery colorbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox, colorbox

I'm using jQuery colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/) on my website. 
And I'm grouping my images in the same class. The lightbox itsellf is working except there is no `NEXT/PREV` button in it.
When I debug it, I see that it shows:

```
id="cboxPrevious" style="display:none;" 
id="cboxNext" style="display:none;"
```

Here is my code :

```
<div class="diagram">
    <div><a href="IMAGE URL" class="group1 cboxElement"><img src="IMAGE URL"></a></div>
    <div><a href="IMAGE URL" class="group1 cboxElement"><img src="IMAGE URL"></a></div>
</div>
```

May I know what goes wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: This is the JS:
$('.group1').colorbox();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the used library has some setting to show the Navigation button. check its documentation with more detail, but for this problem the below code also works:

```
.cboxPrevious, .cboxNext {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: $(selector).colorbox({arrowKey: true});


use this setting to enable that. You can see full dcumentation here : http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: Thanks Saeed, yes, i've referred to the documentation and followed the example, and still it's not working... (after setting arrowKey: true which is also the default).

Comment: Maybe I need to see the full code, please provide a codeSanBox or codepen snippet if you can, to see the problem directly :)

Comment: Sorry.. i just realized the most important JS is wrong.. "rel" was missing. Thank you anyway for your attention :)